# Loading picked contact in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, contacts

To make sure the data was sent correctly, I used toast. At first I thought it worked well, but it has some problems.

1. picking on any contacts outputs the same data.
2. Anyway it worked somewhat, but it does not show data to the recyclerview.

What should I do?..I really need your help.

**MainActivity**

```
public class RegisterContacts extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    final ArrayList<Contact> datas = new ArrayList<>();
    Button contacts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_contacts);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listView_contacts);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(datas, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        contacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_contacts);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkPermission();
        } else {
            contacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    intent.setData(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private final int REQ_CODE = 100;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void checkPermission() {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
            String permArr[] = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    , Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS};

            requestPermissions(permArr, REQ_CODE);
        } else {
            contacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQ_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                contacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "~", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Contact contact = new Contact();

        switch (requestCode) {
            case (1) :
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String contactId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);

                        while(phones.moveToNext()){
                            String tel = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                            //showSelectedNumber(name, tel);

                            contact.setName(name);
                            contact.addTel(tel);

                            datas.add(contact);
                        }
                        phones.close();

                    }
                    c.close();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    //public void showSelectedNumber(String name, String tel) {
        Toast.makeText(this, name + ": " + tel, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.Holder> {

    ArrayList<Contact> datas;
    Context context;

    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Contact> datas, Context context) {
        this.datas = datas;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);
        Holder holder = new Holder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
        final Contact contact = datas.get(position);

        holder.contacts_Name.setText(contact.getName());
        holder.contacts_Tel.setText(contact.getTelOne());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return datas.size();
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView contacts_cardView;
        TextView contacts_Name,contacts_Tel;
        ImageButton btnCancel;

        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            contacts_cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_cardView);
            contacts_Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_Name);
            contacts_Tel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_Tel);
            btnCancel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

            btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            });
        }
    }
}
```

**contact**

```
public class Contact {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<String> tel;

    public Contact(){
        name = new String();
        tel = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public String getTelOne(){
        if(tel.size() > 0)
            return tel.get(0);
        else
            return null;
    }

    public void setTel(ArrayList<String> tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    public void addTel(String tel){
        this.tel.add(tel);
    }

    public void removeTel(String tel){
        this.tel.remove(tel);
    }
}
```

> problem 2's error

```
: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy

> this is common logcat which occured when I run app.
2019-08-14 12:35:27.710 8634-8634/com.example.asus.justtrustme W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@f712f7e
2019-08-14 12:35:28.299 8634-8634/com.example.asus.justtrustme E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2019-08-14 12:35:28.347 8634-8634/com.example.asus.justtrustme I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

2019-08-14 12:37:02.125 1613-1690/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 13846040 , only wrote 13692240
2019-08-14 12:37:02.359 8548-8580/? W/PlayCommon: [489] PlayEventLogger.getAuthToken: No account for auth token provided

W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@f712f7e
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: You mean,your recycleview is not showing data?

Comment: @Kabir yes..it's so hard because this is first time in recyclerview

Comment: Ok Sure,but post your whole logcat for error 2 here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayList have no data in starting of activity,So after fetching contact list,you should call recycleView adapter and pass your list data inside adapter.
Change your code like this :

```
public class RegisterContacts extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    final ArrayList<Contact> datas = new ArrayList<>();
    Button contacts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_contacts);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listView_contacts);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

      //  adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(datas, this);<--Remove this line from here
      //  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);<--Remove this line from here

        contacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_contacts);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkPermission();
        } else {
            contacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    intent.setData(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private final int REQ_CODE = 100;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void checkPermission() {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
            String permArr[] = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    , Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS};

            requestPermissions(permArr, REQ_CODE);
        } else {
            contacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQ_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                contacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "~", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Contact contact = new Contact();

        switch (requestCode) {
            case (1) :
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String contactId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);

                        while(phones.moveToNext()){
                            String tel = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                            //showSelectedNumber(name, tel);

                            contact.setName(name);
                            contact.addTel(tel);

                            datas.add(contact);
                        }
                        phones.close();

                    }
                    c.close();
                    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(datas, this);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
                break;
        }
    }

    //public void showSelectedNumber(String name, String tel) {
        Toast.makeText(this, name + ": " + tel, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

You can refere this document more details details:[doc](http://sonevalley.blogspot.com/2015/12/retrieving-list-of-contacts-in-android.html)

For recycleview item click.Here is code:

```
public Holder(View itemView) {
     super(itemView);
   contacts_cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_cardView);
   contacts_Name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_Name);
   contacts_Tel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_Tel);
   btnCancel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

   btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   });

  itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      int pos=getAdapterPosition();
     Toast.makeText(context,"Pick contact :"+datas.get(pos).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
  });
}
```

For more details of recycleview item click listener check:[doc](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/)

Comment: OMG..!! It shows in recyclerview. Thanks a lot. Now, problem is that I just click one contact , but it makes two cardview. And  picking any contacts outputs the same contact. 
EX) I click b or c contact, but only show a contact

Comment: You mean,you want to click particular contact item ?

Comment: I want to show tom's contact when I pick tom.
EX) amy - amy, tom - tom like this.
and I edit my error..there is no red warning because it's not error, but it just dosen't show data in recyclerview.
so, I wrote common logcat.

Comment: If you find help from my answer,then accept my answer please.

Comment: Sorry becuase I'm late. Actually I can't solve it, but your answer is helpful, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks you so much,But Sure inform here of your problem.i will be glad if i can help you.